# Adding Text Containing Superscripts and Subscripts to a Plot in R With More Than Two New Lines

Tags: r, plot, text

I'm trying to add text to a plot that should appear on more than two new lines. The text contains special characters (like superscripts and subscripts), so I know I have to use either a combination of `bquote()` and `atop()` or a combination of `expression()` and `paste()`. I've tried a few things, and nothing seems to work.

```
plot(0, type = 'n')
Horizontal_Axis_Value <- mean(par('usr')[1:2])
Vertical_Axis_Values <- seq(from = par('usr')[3], to = par('usr')[4], length.out = 6)
Vertical_Axis_Values <- Vertical_Axis_Values[-c(1, length(Vertical_Axis_Values))]
text(Horizontal_Axis_Value, Vertical_Axis_Values[4], labels = bquote(atop('Variable Name, Line 1', 'Variable Name, Line 2', 'cm' ^ 2 * ' hr' ^ '-1')))
text(Horizontal_Axis_Value, Vertical_Axis_Values[3], labels = bquote(atop('Variable Name, Line 1', atop('Variable Name, Line 2', 'cm' ^ 2 * ' hr' ^ '-1'))))
text(Horizontal_Axis_Value, Vertical_Axis_Values[2], labels = expression(paste('Variable Name, Line 1\nVariable Name, Line 2\ncm' ^ '2' * ' hr' ^ '-1')))
text(Horizontal_Axis_Value, Vertical_Axis_Values[1], labels = expression(paste('Variable Name, Line 1\nVariable Name, Line 2\n\ncm' ^ '2' * ' hr' ^ '-1')))
```

[image]

I want the subscripts and the superscripts to appear properly - I want all three (or more) lines to appear, I want the three (or more) lines to all be of the same font size, and I want there to be no large gaps in the text. Are there any good solutions?

I've found a workaround using nested `atop()` functions and an empty character string (see below), but I'm still hoping to find something better that can handle my scenario of three lines above.

```
plot(0, type = 'n')
Horizontal_Axis_Value <- mean(par('usr')[1:2])
Vertical_Axis_Values <- mean(par('usr')[3:4])
text(Horizontal_Axis_Value, Vertical_Axis_Values, labels = bquote(atop(atop('Variable Name, Line 1', 'Variable Name, Line 2'), atop('cm' ^ 2 * ' hr' ^ '-1', ''))))
```

[image]